# Как умножать между собой переменные?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно выполнить следующие арифметическое действие, компилятор думает, что это указатель, а не оператор умножения. `cost` и `procent` — имена переменных.

```
now_cost = procent * (1 / 100) * cost;
```

Comment: 1. С чего вы взяли, что компилятор так думает? 2. `now_cost` всегда будет равно нулю, т. к. `(1 / 100)` равно 0 (целочисленное деление).

Comment: и как мне быть?

Comment: А что вам надо-то? Какая задача стоит?

Comment: просто идти спать :)

Comment: мне нужно узнать процент от суммы

Comment: `(double)now_cost = (double) procent *   cost / 100`.  Ваши объявления нужно показывать, чтобы люди знали что из себя представляют эти переменные

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: И, кажется, вы неправильно пытаетесь  вычислять процент от числа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны вычисления с плавающей точкой.

Все зависит от типов `procent` и `cost`. Если они целые - то нужно

```
now_cost = procent * 0.01 * cost;
```

Если нет - достаточно

```
now_cost = procent / 100 * cost;
```

И `now_cost` должна быть нецелой, а по произойдет отброс дробной части результата.